# MUI-X DataGrid issues with singleSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having some issues with the singleSelect type on the community version of x-data-grid. My issue happens when I go to edit the row. My singleSelect is a list of data as follows.

Here is how my DataGrid is created. I know the editMode row is unnecessary at this time since there is only one column, but eventually I would like to use the row edit mode.

```
<DataGrid editMode="row" slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }} checkboxSelection={dataGridCheckboxes} rows={gridData || []} columns={columnsSetup} />
```

Here is how I setup the column. I only have 1 column at this time. The data pulls from a websocket between the react client and a websocket server to "simulate" pulling data from a database.

```
const columnsSetup = [
    {
        field: "test",
        headerName: "Object Dropdown",
        editable: true,
        type: "singleSelect",
        defaultValue: { short: "T2", numerical: 1 },
        valueOptions: [
            { short: "T2", numerical: 1 },
            { short: "T3", numerical: 2 },
            { short: "T4", numerical: 3 },
            { short: "T5", numerical: 4 },
            { short: "T6", numerical: 5 },
            { short: "T7", numerical: 6 },
            { short: "T8", numerical: 7 },
        ],
        valueFormatter: ({ value }) => {
            return value.short;
        },
        getOptionValue: (value) => value.numerical,
        getOptionLabel: (value) => value.short, // To populate the singleSelect dropdown list.
        sortComparator: (v1, v2) => {
            return gridNumberComparator(v1.numerical, v2.numerical);
        }
    },
];
```

Here is an example of how the data gets sent from the websocket.

```
[
    {
        "test": {
            "short": "T2",
            "numerical": 1
        },
    },
    {
        "test": {
            "short": "T5",
            "numerical": 4
        },
    },
]
```

Now, the numerical part of the object is for sorting purposes. Each "short" will be a different name and won't have numbers in the coming future, so I figured the numerical part was the only way to be able to sort it the way I wanted.

When loaded into the grid, everything shows up properly. The issue I get is when I double click to edit, I am getting an error in the JS console and the select goes blank. I can still update the value, but do not want the select to go blank right as the edit starts.

This is the error I am receiving in the console.

```
You have provided an out-of-range value `[object Object]` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`.
```

In edit mode, the values still show up in the dropdown, but it goes blank as mentioned. It seems to be an issue only for the object in a singleSelect. Strings work just fine!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide on the value, not the object for `singleSelect`. You can change the column definition this way:

```js
const columnsSetup = [
    {
        // ...
        defaultValue: 1
        valueGetter: ({ value }) => value.numerical
    }
]
```